# Bloquear teclas alt+f4 en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows, windows10

Estoy haciendo un formulario de ingreso con C# y WindowsForm en Windows 10, el cual necesito que el usuario rellene para así poder sacar estadísticas de uso, pero tengo el problema de que aplicando ciertos comandos de windows (Alt+F4, Ctrl+Alt+Supr, Alt+Tab) los usuarios pueden cerrar el formulario o saltarlo, estuve investigando sobre el tema y nada de lo que probé funciona, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: con esas cosas cierra tus programas. Es logico, si se lo impedis, se le puede bloquear la pc. Tal vez si nos contas el escenario podamos encontrar algo mejor?

Comment: Te comento se implementará en un laboratorio de computación y los usuarios necesitan meter sus datos por ejemplo rut, nombre, carrera y software que utilizará, con todos estos datos en diciembre se hacen estadísticas de las carreras que mas utilizan los equipos, que softwares son los más utilizados, los horarios con más usuarios conectados al mismo tiempo, etc, por eso no se debe cerrar o saltar el formulario.

Comment: Entonces deberias tener un login tipo kiosco que bloquee todo windows hasta que no le des acceso al usuario.

Comment: No sé como aplicar eso

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta a esto es que a tu formulario le asignes el evento de onFormClosing la siguiente funcion

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing;
}
```

Tambien podrias probar con esta otra

```
private void form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt || this.ModifierKeys == Keys.F4) 
    { 
        e.Cancel = true; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvió el primero, ahora estoy averiguando sobre el Alt+Tab

Comment: Si te fue de utilidad, recorda votar como respuesta correcta y puntito arriba :D

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una "solución", es un dll que encontré por ahí. Este dll bloquea las teclas especiales (TAB, Windows, Alt, etc).

En C# hay que agregar la referencia "DesktopControl.dll"

```
//Agregar el using
using DesktopControl;

//En el Form poner esto
KunLibertad_DesktopControl Desk = new KunLibertad_DesktopControl();

//Para bloquear las teclas especiales poner esto
Desk.SpecialKeyButtons(false);
```

Dejo el link de donde encontré el dll, en el video se aplica a VB.NET
[VB.NET - Deshabilitar tecla de Windows y combinaciones de teclas con DesktopControl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7-JGJC0UYk), ademas dejo el link de descarga del dll [DesktopControl](http://www.mediafire.com/file/wrwxg04pvt1230g/DesktopControl.rar)